# Can you explain these unusual phrases in English to me?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[Source](http://blogs.timesofindia.indiatimes.com/mrsfunnybones/kohinoor-and-other-british-gems/)

I am a non-native speaker.I've always had formal English learning.There're a few things which confuse me in English being spoken informally.

> For more information please turn to your backside…

What does the writer intend to say by this?Is it refers to Modi standing behind them(the prince and the princess)?

> He replies, ‘Oh bloomin ‘eck brilliant! You Indians speak English all right.’

Now the writer says this is ungrammatical and it was 'rather inevitable' we would learn English.What is the ungrammatical thing and what is the meaning?

Comment: It really is funny :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word [backside](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/backside) is an informal word meaning bottom- the part of your body that you sit on.

> For more information please turn to your backside

The writer probably meant *turn to the back of the letter*, but misunderstood what **backside** means. It is not ungrammatical, but would probably be impossible unless you are a yoga expert.

The response is also grammatically correct but very informal: the spelling is an attempt at an east London accent, and there should probably be a comma after **Oh** and before **brilliant**. "Bloomin 'eck" is a euphemism for "bloody hell", and "all right" means "satisfactorily".

Comment: Why the second phrase'as been considered as ungrammatical by the article-writer?

Comment: @AnubhavSingh, that is a good question: I think that you would have to ask the article-writer. I get the impression that she is less familiar with informal English than she thinks: certainly her understanding of the word "Cheerio" is incorrect. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cheerio

Answer (score 1):

The section *"For more information please turn to your backside…"* should be read in conjunction with some the words that follow, namely *"[they] finally decided to flip the letter over ..."*.

The writer probably intended to say *"For more information please see the reverse of this letter"*.